# Remove a wild "-" dash from active class anchor tag

Tags: jquery, html

I have used this https://jsfiddle.net/u9d1ewsh/ to add pagination in my table, which works fine. The issue is a wild "-" dash appearing on the active page number (please see pic below). I have checked the same using Developer tools, its not a character and it happens to be only for active class. **What do I do to remove it ?**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tblAH1').after('<div id="pager" style="" ></div>');
    var rowsShown = 5;
    var rowsTotal = $('#tblAH1 tbody tr').length;
    var numPages = rowsTotal / rowsShown;
    for (i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
        var pageNum = i + 1;
        $('#pager').append('<a href="#" rel="' + i + '">' + pageNum + '</a> ');
    }
    $('#tblAH1 tbody tr').hide();
    $('#tblAH1 tbody tr').slice(0, rowsShown).show();
    $('#pager a:first').addClass('active');
    $('#pager a').bind('click', function () {

        $('#pager a').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        var currPage = $(this).attr('rel');
        var startItem = currPage * rowsShown;
        var endItem = startItem + rowsShown;
        $('#tblAH1 tbody tr').css('opacity', '0.0').hide().slice(startItem, endItem).
        css('display', 'table-row').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});


#pager {
            display: inline-block;
            align-items: center;
        }

            #pager a {
                color: black;
                float: left;
                padding: 4px 8px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }

                #pager a.active {
                    background-color: #fb9a55;
                    padding: 4px 8px;
                    color: white;
                }

                #pager a:hover:not(.active) {
                    background-color: #ddd;
                }
```

[image]

Comment: Is it not happening in the fiddle?

Comment: surprisingly No. For my code it happening in both IE and chrome.

Comment: Could be because you have not added any styles in fiddle? Can you add the CSS in the fiddle?

Comment: You've an extra `-` somewhere in the script...

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I checked the script (pasted in question) .. there is no extra - . Not even in developer tools.

Comment: @void Let me try

Comment: Have you checked the HTML part ?

Comment: @Sak It's kinda hard to test the problem when the code on this page and the code on the jsfiddle is not the same

Comment: You need to reproduce the issue in a fiddle so we could help.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki I understand but unable to reproduce the same on fiddle.

Comment: If you post with html part then, it will be easier to debug.

Comment: @BijayaKumarOli Trust me it's nothing to do with html part.. its a simple <table>

Comment: a wild dash appears (sorry couldnt resist)

Comment: @Alex a 9gagger ?

Comment: @Sak dude... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following css, the line may be generated by a pseudo selector

```
.active:before,.active:after {
  content:"";
  display:none;
}
```

if you have other libraries like bootstrap its possible that the `active` class is styled with that line, ether you override the css or you change your class name

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki why do you think its a "workaround hack"? how do you know this will not solve the problem?

Comment: Since you don't know from where the extra dash comes.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki But does it fix your problem? If so, you know what to look for.

Comment: my intuition tells me that the dash comes from the pseudo selector because he says it doesn't appear in the html, so it should be ether css or js, we can rule out the js (we have it) so css remains

Comment: Then you should look for the pseudo selector that add the dash and remove it, that will be the valid answer

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$('#pager').append('<a href="#" rel="' + i + '">' + pageNum.replace('-','') + '</a> ');
```

Comment: Cant replace it because a real "-" isn't there.